# How to emulate the int* c pointer in jna?

Tags: java-native-interface, jna

I used this:

```
int[] myPointer = new int[1];
```

and it works. But isn't there a better way?

Comment: Very good it works...if you answe me I'll give you the "correct". While we are at it could you tell me about the "long long" too so that I don't have to open a new topic? I used the java "long" but I am afraid losing data...

Comment: `long long` is 64 bits, so representing with Java `long` is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`IntByReference`](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.1.0/com/sun/jna/ptr/IntByReference.html) or [`Memory(4)`](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.1.0/com/sun/jna/Memory.html) will also work.